# "You replied to this message on" title in add-in form region

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007-addin, outlook-form

Is there any way I can add the "You replied to this message on XXX" title (the current outlook one has a nice exclamation mark too!) easily to my own form region?

Perhaps define a placeholder in the form region and fill it somehow? I'm using C++.

Thanks,

Nili

Answer (score 0):

Look in the XXXFactory class (XXX = your region name), in the FormRegionInitializing event handler.  There  you have access to e.OutlookItem which you could cast to a MailItem to get the date sent.  Then set the mainifest's FormRegionName as you like.